# Engineering mechanics of cutting blades

Tags: mechanical-engineering, applied-mechanics

There are several machines that have (rotating) cutting blades. For example the kitchen aid Vorwerk Thermomix can cut pieces of Food in hundreds of pieces within a few seconds. But why it is so?

If the blade hits something, there must act some Forces that cut it into pieces. How to compute the Forces that act on a blade to the Thing that the blade is cutting? Can I also compute stress values during the cutting process?

Is there any literature in Engineering mechanics that unravels the mystery of cutting?

And I wonder why knives are classified with Rockwell hardness. I would be happy about a Basic introduction into this topic.

Comment: Check out texts on machining lathes, drills etc and also resistance of materials ie cutting tomatoes compared to cutting beef and heat treatment ....

Comment: Rockwell Hardness indicates how much force is required to deform a material, thus giving an indication as to the expected life of the blade.

Comment: I am sure there is engineering literature, but that is off topic for this site.

Comment: @LSelter I'm not sure if hardness is really what you would want to look at here, at least not exclusively.  That wouldn't really account for pieces of the tip fracturing.

Comment: Manufacturing texts should cover this information in good detail.

Comment: @JMac I am aware that there is a lot more to understanding blade properties, that wasn't the question though.

Comment: @LSelter there were several questions.... forces, stress, cutting, hardness....